# Excluding Instagram share option from uiactivtyviewcontroller IOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, instagram, sharing, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am currently working on a project which demands to remove Instagram sharing option from UIActivtyViewController but i am unable to remove share on instagram option. 
Below is my code

```
let img: UIImage = snapShot(button: button)
        let objectsToShare: [Any] = [img]
        let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
        activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityType.postToInstagram]
        activityVC.completionWithItemsHandler = {(activityType: UIActivityType?, _ completed: Bool, _ returnedItems: [Any]?, _ activityError: Error?) -> Void in

       if completed {
          //my code 
       }
)}
```

i have also ovveride the UIActivtyType

```
extension UIActivityType {
    @available(iOS 7.0, *)
    public static let postToInstagram: UIActivityType = {
        return UIActivityType.init(rawValue: "com.burbn.instagram.shareextension")
    }()
}
```

Kindly there is anyone who can guide me.
Many thanks :)

Comment: `excludedActivityTypes` should be all that you need.  What is you goal with the extension?  it seems to me that would make the excludedActivityTypes not work.

Comment: use inthis `com.burbn.instagram.shareextension` of `com.instagram.exclusivegram`

Comment: friend i did this in obj-c. I have whole working code.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik comment is useful for you too.

Comment: can you please share the code @Mukesh

Comment: @JonRose i want to exclude instagram sharing option from my activity.... simple

Comment: You can also check condition before sharing `UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "instagram://app"))`

Comment: 'activityVC.excludedActivityTypes =   [UIActivityType(rawValue: "com.instagram.photo"), UIActivityType(rawValue: "com.instagram.exclusivegram"), UIActivityType(rawValue: "com.burbn.instagram.shareextension"),UIActivityType.init("com.burbn.instagram.shareextension")]'    here is the code @Anbu.Karthik ..its not working too

Comment: @Mukesh i think you have not got my point ... i want to share some images etc on facebook , twitter etc.. And the requirement is that we have to remove the other options like whatspp, instagram , etc from uictivtyviewcontroller ...

Comment: Hello All .. After a deep R&D we came to the conclusion that Instagram, whats-app, messages etc cannot be excluded from share activity unless we implement a custom share activity instead of default uiactivtyviewcontroller ....